# On an integral equality.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

I am wondering if the following fact is true:

Given two integrable functions $a(x), b(x) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \ell \le a(x) + b(x)   \le L $ for all $x$ where $0<\ell< L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that there always exist a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \ell \le c  \le L$ and

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} a(x) f(x) + b(x) g(x) dx = c \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) + g(x) dx $$

where $f(x), g(x) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two integrable functions such that $a(x) f(x)$ and $b(x) g(x)$ are both integrable (the expression makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. An example is $f(x)=e^{-|x|},g(x)=-e^{-|x|}, a(x)=e^{-|x|}+1, b(x)=e^{-|x|}+1$ for $|x|>1$ and $b(x)=1$ for $|x|<1$. We can take $l=1$ and $L=3$. Here RHS is $0$ whatever $c$ you take and LHS is not $0$.